Google AppSheet chart only offers _RowNumber as column
I have Google Sheets spreadsheet for tracking events that has several columns:

Date
Time
Duration
Description
Handled (yes/no)
Action

Now I want to use Google AppSheets to create an app that shows statistics about the entries.
I wanted to create one view with a chart that displays the data as a column series that displays the number of handled vs. unhandled events by date.
In other words, the X axis is supposed to be the date and the Y axis is to be the entries with handled = Y and handled = N as two stacked bars.
However when I try to add chart columns, the only option it gives me is the auto-generated column _RowNumber.
What am I doing wrong?
